# Apache ReWrite Rule Questions

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

A few questions:

1. I have several domains hosted on the same server and I created some ReWrite rules that for specific {REQUEST_URI} gets redirected elsewhere. I copied these rules to each and every Virtual Host. Can I just put these rules in a file and do something like:

   `<VirtualHost>`

   ```
   ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.net
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/<directory>
   ServerName <domain>
   ServerAlias www.<domain>
   ErrorLog logs/www_<domain>-error_log
   CustomLog logs/www_<domain>-access_log common
   RewriteEngine on
   Include rewrite_rules.conf
   ```
2. How can one create a rule that says if requests come in on specific domains to re-direct to a generic 'For Sale' page. Example, Same they type in www.Allertia.com and I want them to be directed to a For Sale Page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you can do that. The `Include` directive acts as if the contents of the named file were literally included.
2. Assuming you want the same "for sale" page to show up for all of the domains:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName forsale1.com
       ServerAlias www.forsale1.com
       ServerAlias forsale2.com
       ServerAlias www.forsale2.com
       ...

       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteRule .* /var/www/html/path/to/forsale.html
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

   This will not change the URL that appears in the browser. If you want to perform an HTTP redirect so that the URL in the browser *does* change, you could add `[R]` after the rewrite rule. (Or you could use `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` which might be a little quicker, if your server is under high load)

Answer (score 0):

You want something that matches against the incoming HTTP Host: header, so a rule such as this will work:

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www.allertia.com
RewriteRule /  http://example.com/for-sale.html [R,L]
```

The issue you'll find is that if you say "Rewrite all requests for http://www.alertia.com to http://alertia.com/for-sale.html" you'll get a redirection loop.  So redirecting to an un-related domain is simplest.

However if you wish you can create a rule which says "For all requests not equal to /for-sale.html, do the rewrite":

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} www.allertia.com
RewriteRule !/for-sale.html$  http://www.allertia.com/for-sale.html [R,L]
```

Obviously you'll need to update the path for the "for sale" page.  You'll probably also want to include the rules twice:

- http://allertia.com/
- http://www.allertia.com/

Comment: @Steve Kemp - Do I need to create a Virtual Host for Allertia to achieve this or is there a generic way to have ReWrite rules evaluated and acted upon at a non Virtual Host level? I have a number of domains for sale and if I can avoid creating a Virtual Host for each one that would be best!

Comment: I was working on the assumption these rules were global - so you didn't need  to create a virtual host for them.

Comment: @Steve - Oh, sorry, where do global rules go in httpd.conf?

Comment: Add the rules I suggested to your "rewrite_rules.conf" file - the one you demonstrate using already in your config.

Comment: @Steve oh, #1 has nothing to do with #2 above. They are different questions. I don't understand where to put/how to use ReWrite rules without creating a virtual host for each domain. Can you explain?

Comment: Just have the rule in the block governing the directory (e.g. www or htdocs) and not in a virtual host and it will be global

Comment: @Devin - When I put the rules in my `<Directory "/var/www/html">` like `#RewriteEngine on
    #Rewritebase /
    # For-Sale - Domains
    #RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www.allertia.com [NC,OR]
    #RewriteCond %{http_host} !^allertia.com [NC,OR]
    #RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www.iph0wnd.com [NC,OR]
    #RewriteCond %{http_host} !^iph0wnd.com [NC,OR]
    #RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www.paymetowait.com [NC,OR]
    #RewriteCond %{http_host} !^paymetowait.com [NC]
    #RewriteRule /  http://6colors.net/for-sale/index.html [R,L]` N

Comment: @Devin -Nothing works, I think something circular might be going on. Or at least Safari thinks so

Comment: @Devin - the rules are not commented out, but they were when I copied this into the comment and the RewriteRule is: `RewriteRule / http://6colors.net/for_sale/index.html [R,L]`

Comment: So you uncommented it and it works?

Comment: Apache ignores global rules if any virtual hosts are defined.

Comment: `RewriteOptions Inherit` will allow you to use global rules with virtual hosts. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#vhosts